# Searching for strings containing a string parameter using web api (ASP). Data stored in a JSON containing list of files in a network drive

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use AngularJS to query a string to web api (ASP) who handles a JSON file with filepaths to a network drive, and get back all filenames containing the searched for string. I can't seem to find any good solution for this.

My Model :

```
    namespace RetGet.data
   {
        [DataContract]
        public class RetFil
    {

        [DataMember]

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]

        public string RetPath { get; set; }

    }
    }
```

In my controller :

```
    //Ref to the model
    RetFil retfil = new RetFil();
    //Network drive path (Might have to change/Access permissions)
    string dirPath = @"HERE IS THE NETWORK DRIVE PATH";

    List<string> files;
    List<object> filesFormatted;



    public void SetUpLists()
    {

        //Collects all the .ret files in the dirPath and it's subfolders.
        files = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.ret", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        filesFormatted = new List<object>();


    } 

    // GET: api/Ret/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(RetFil))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRet(string id)
    {

        SetUpLists();

        //Adds each filename and format it (removing "\" from the file path) to the list of objects 
        foreach (var file in files)
        {

            var pathToString = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\"));
            if (pathToString.Contains(id))
            {
                filesFormatted.Add(new { pathToString });
            }

        }

        //Returns the list of object. Web Api will convert to JSON automatic.

        return Ok(filesFormatted); 
    }
```

When I try to GET something from AngularJS, I manage to get the entire list of path. It takes a LOOOONG time (why?) and I can't manage to get a string containing the string parameter.

Any suggestions how I solve this?

Comment: Is it taking long on the directory search or the return to the client?

Comment: When debugging network with chrome dev tool, it's the "waiting" part that takes time. All other is just a few milliseconds.